# Python gives me last value of list when I ask it to give the value at -1

Tags: python, python-3.7

I am on python 3.7.1.

I am working with data structures, and when using lists, I ran into a bug.
When I try to access index -1, python gives me the last entry in the list.

I opened python shell, and ran the following commands:

```py
>>> l = [0,1,2]
>>> l[-1]
2
>>> l[3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    l[3]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is probably due to a bug on python 3.7.1, but is there a way other than updating python that fixes this? I'm in the middle of a project.

Comment: python the index start with 0

Comment: Im puzzled as to what you thought actually would happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Negative indices mean you're counting from the right, not the left. so l[-1] accesses the last index in the array, l[-2] access the second to last, etc.

l[3] doesn't work because you have indices of 0, 1, and 2, there is no 3.

Answer (score 3):

You have the list:
l = [0,1,2] the length of the list is 3, you have 3 items but the indexes start in 0, so:

l [0] = 0

l [1] = 1

l [2] = 2

l[3] is out of range since the list goes from 0 to 2

When you use negative indexes you move from the right.

l [-2] = 1